# Limitations of SARIMA model - Challenge

Tags: python, r, statistics, statsmodels, arima

I am not quite used to ARIMA's models but I believe I reached the on of the limitations of these autoregressive models, could you please check it out and tell me if I am wrong:

Find the data (with no virus, guaranteed) in the following Gofile link: https://gofile.io/d/RAlgkc

I have a timeseries (monthly aggregated) that looks like the following:

[image]

I see NO trend at all and the statistical test confirm stationarity:

> ADF Statistic: -4.858951
> p-value: 0.000042
> Lags used: 12.000000
> The nobs or number of observations used for the Critical Values: 479.000000
> Critical Values:
> 1%: -3.444
> 5%: -2.868
> 10%: -2.570
>
> KPSS Statistic: 0.064377
> p-value: 0.100000.
> lags: 18.000000
> Critical Values:
> 10%: 0.347
> 5%: 0.463
> 2.5%: 0.574
> 1%: 0.739

Perhaps my only concern is the p-value of the KPSS, which is quite above a 5% threshold... Anyway statistical tests points to stationarity so lets move on.

In autoregression correlograms (ACF and PACF) I can see a clear seasonality (remember, x-axis are months)

[image]

High correlation with small lags, so I define the orders of this SARIMA model as (1, 0, 1) - (1, 0, 1, 12). Providing quite a consistent results:

[image]

From here on, I do not like the results all, this is the prediction compared to my test (splited data).

[image]

ARIMA is just describing the average seasonality for the test period (~ 120 months) WITHOUT taking into consideration the order parameteres in between season... Despite this, the residuals are all uncorrelated

[image]

So my question is, is it me (probably), that I am not describing properly the order and the seasonal order of the time series or this is the maximum I should expected from a SARIMA model?
What concerns me more is that the residuals are uncorrelated...

Your help, opinions, feedback I much appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you share the data it would be easier to help.

Comment: Thanks Chris,
Here I have just generated a csv file and upload it in gofile:
https://gofile.io/d/RAlgkc

Contains the entire dataset